# CDK synth not validating lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-cdk

I have a node CDK project with some python lambdas, I have put some code into the handler of the lambda that i have specified in my stack this being the `execute` function. I add some gibberish into the start of that function so it would fail or not be valid. I type `cdk synth` this still generates a template, shouldn't this do some validation on the lambdas, if not how do we validate these lambdas before deploying?
Thanks

Comment: Try to run `npm run build` before `cdk synth`

Comment: Tried it but it didn't seem to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html):

> The Toolkit provides the ability to convert one or more AWS CDK stacks
> to AWS CloudFormation templates and related assets (a process called
> synthesis) and to deploy your stacks to an AWS account.

The `cdk synth` does not do any additional validation on the underlying Cloudformation resources -- it simply converts the CDK code into Cloudformation templates.

You have to add in this functionality yourself before deployment. One way to achieve this could be running a local [SAM test suite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html).